# Sort a multidimensional array and retain its keys

Tags: php

I currently use a usort with a custom function to sort a multidimensionial array:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['count'] - $b['count'];
});
```

This will sort the array fine, but it looses the key information.  Given the array:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [foo] => bar
            [count] => 11
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [foo] => baz
            [count] => 1
        )
)
```

`usort` will produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo] => baz
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [foo] => bar
            [count] => 11
        )
)
```

I would like to sort by `count`, but retain the keys `[3]` and `[7]`.  Unfortunately `usort` will set the keys to `[0]` and `[1]`.

Comment: Thats not really a sort then.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) instead, it preserves the original keys

Comment: See also: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php for a list of sorting functions and which of those keep keys.